# Как получить короткое имя типа?

Tags: c#, .net

Вызывая код

```
typeof(int).Name
```

я получаю "Int32"

А как мне получить короткие имена типов? То есть вместо Int32 - int, Int64 - long и тд. Ручной маппинг не предлагать, это я и сам могу. Просто подумал, может есть более красивое решение.

Comment: вроде нету, так как это алиасы и после компиляции их просто нет

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.GetTypeOutput`

```
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

var type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(int));

Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).Name);
Console.WriteLine(compiler.GetTypeOutput(type));
```

Output:

```
Int32
int
```

Comment: решение нашел на [so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4369744/3373603)